# Button Listener JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sockets, debugging, button, listener

I have an interesting bug, I don't know if it comes from a point that I ignore from javascript but it doesn't make sense at all!

[image: Example]

It is a small messaging application where you can play chifoumi.

Here in the photo we have received 2 game requests, characterized with the "answer (Répondre au jeu)" button, the button is deactivated when we have answered! So far yes, BUT the problem is that the first button you see here is no longer listened to, in fact, it is as if the listener associated with the button had flown by itself.

[image: The button has lost its listener]

So I don't understand why the button loses its listener; knowing that before clicking on the other it works perfectly (pressing a button just fills the text box at the bottom, if I don't send it the button remains active).

Here is my code :

```
socket.on("chifoumi", function(result) {

    var win = document.getElementById("content");

    var date = new Date(result.date);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();

    if (date.getHours() < 10)
        hours = "0" + date.getHours();
    if (date.getMinutes() < 10)
        minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    if (date.getSeconds() < 10)
        seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

    let main = document.getElementsByTagName("MAIN");

    if (result.from == currentPseudo) {
        main[0].innerHTML += "<p class=\"chifoumi\">" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +
            seconds + " - [chifoumi] : Défi envoyé à " + result.to + "</p>";
    } else if (result.from != currentPseudo) {


        main[0].innerHTML += "<p class=\"chifoumi\">" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +
            seconds + " - [chifoumi] : " + result.from + " te défi à Paper-Rock-Scissors-Lizard-Spock. <button class=" + result.from + " name = \"btn\"> Répondre au jeu </button></p > ";
        win.className = "buzz";
        buttonListener();

    }
});
```

Each time I add a new button, I update all the listeners of my buttons, because same problem when I added a new button, the others lost their listener !

```
function buttonListener() {

    let btn = document.getElementsByName("btn");
    console.log(btn);
    for (let bt of btn) {
        ////LISTENER MULTI BOUTON
        console.log(bt);
        bt.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            startGame = 1;
            msgChiff = "/chifoumi @" + this.className + " :";
            document.getElementById("monMessage").value = "/chifoumi @" + this.className + " :";
        });
    }
}
```

I don't think the rest of my code will do you any good. I do not touch the listener elsewhere.

I thank you in advance..

Comment: Is the button disabled? If it is disabled, no click events will be detected.

Comment: I was talking about the first button that remains active, sorry I fixed the typing error.

Comment: well if the code goes into `result.from == currentPseudo`, no event listeners are added

Comment: This condition just makes it possible to differentiate the sender from the challenge and the receiver, in our case we are the receiver, so we will always go into the else. And, before you click any button, they all work! The listeners are there, here click on the button then send, deletes the listeners associated with this button. How is possible?

Comment: in fact, clicking on a button displays a text at the bottom. The buttons don't turn off until I send the response.
Before sent, the buttons work both show me different text at the bottom! But if I click to send, then the target button deactivates this (this is normal) but the other loses its listener.

Comment: a video would be much simpler for you to understand my problem;  can we upload a video here?

Comment: It's probably because you are setting innerHTML. By setting innerHTML, you are telling the browser to delete everything that's inside main[0], and then add the things in the innerHTML string back. But the innerHTML string doesn't have any event listeners. So, you don't get one. Try using appendElement instead, which adds a new element, without changing any of the others.

Comment: Indeed you are a genius .. a property of innerHTML is reparse all the content of the target node (even if we use + = and the previous content is not deleted) so listeners are removed. I maintain my innerHTML directly on the <p> element and appendChild with main. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on the behalf of user253751

> It's probably because you are setting innerHTML. By setting innerHTML, you are telling the browser to delete everything that's inside main[0], and then add the things in the innerHTML string back. But the innerHTML string doesn't have any event listeners. So, you don't get one. Try using appendElement instead, which adds a new element, without changing any of the others.